# Vue js keep returning "Unknown custom element"

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.7

I'm sure i didn't type anything wrong in my code, because i didn't even change it, but i just keep getting Unknown custom element error in console, here is my code:

app.js
    /**
     * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
     * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
     * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
     */

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app"
});
```

ExampleComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card card-default">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Main File 
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

<template>
    <example-component></example-component>
</template>
/**
* Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
* the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
* or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
*/
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
el: "#app"
});





<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    I'm an example component.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: forgot to define <example-component></example-component> in to your root file.